# Install latest GCC on Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, gcc

So as we all know, theres GCC version `7.1` and I wanted to have it on Fedora. `dnf update` only updates to `6.3.0`, but I have this updating mania, so I really need to have the latest version. I know that I can download its source, configure and install, but then what do I need to uninstall first (nothing, only gcc, all gcc related things), will it install itself in a proper directory, so I won't have to add it to PATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC 6.3 is latest in the current Fedora 25. If you need a newer, you will need to update to Fedora 26 (currently Beta). How to upgrade your system is described in the following wiki page:

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade